# Search one hash for its keys, grab the values, put them in an array and merge the first hash with the second

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with items like

```
{'people'=>'50'},
{'chairs'=>'23'},
{'footballs'=>'5'},
{'crayons'=>'1'},
```

and I have another hash with

```
{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/this-post'},
{'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/that-post'},
{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/nice-post'},
{'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/other-post'},
{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'},
{'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
{'crayons'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-blah'},
{'chairs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-page'},
```

and I want something like the following that takes the first hash and then looks through the second one, grabs all the links for each word and puts them into a array appended onto the end of the hash somehow.

```
{'people', '50' => {'http://www.thing.com/this-post', 'http://www.thing.com/nice-post', 'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'}},
{'footballs', '5' => {'http://www.thing.com/the-post', 'http://www.thing.com/the-post'}},
{'crayons', '1' => {'http://www.thing.com/the-blah'}},
{'chairs', '23' => {'chairs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-page'}},
```

I am very new to Ruby, and I have tried quite a few combinations, and I need some help.

Excuse the example, I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: are those array of Hash ?

Comment: `'50' => {'http://www.thing.com/this-post', 'http://www.thing.com/nice-post', 'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'}` not a valid hash... but an array ? What do you think ? Does array is good, as hash is not valid ?

Comment: To elaborate what @Arup said, you can have a hash (`{'people'=>'50', 'chairs'=>'23'}`) or an array of hashes(`[{'people'=>'50'}, {'chairs'=>'23'}]`).  Please correct your question with an edit (rather than explaining in a comment).

Comment: I've downvoted this question, as there is a _really_ thorough answer from Cary, and you've not responded. You don't have to thank every single poster who answers, but for uncommonly good efforts, I think we should all be happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is some confusion about the format of the data, I will suggest how you might effectively structure both the input and the output.  I will first present some code you could use, then give an example of how it's used, then explain what is happening.

**Code**

```
def merge_em(hash, array)
    hash_keys = hash.keys
    new_hash = hash_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h|
                 h[k] = { qty: hash[k], http: [] } }
    array.each do |h|
      h.keys.each do |k|
        (new_hash.update({k=>h[k]}) { |k,g,http|
          {qty: g[:qty], http: (g[:http] << http)}}) if hash_keys.include?(k)
      end
    end
    new_hash
end
```

**Example**

Here is a hash that I have modified to include a key/value pair that does not appear in the array below:

```
hash = {'people' =>'50', 'chairs'   =>'23', 'footballs'=>'5',
        'crayons'=> '1', 'cat_lives'=> '9'}
```

Below is your array of hashes that is to be merged into `hash`.  You'll see I've added a key/value pair to your hash with key `"chairs"`.  As I hope to make clear, the code is no different (i.e., not simplified) if we know in advance that each hash has only one key value pair.  (Aside: if, for example, we want want the key from a hash `h` that is known to have only one key, we still have to pull out all the keys into an array and then take the only element of the array: `h.keys.first`).

I have also added a hash to the array that has no key that is among `hash`'s keys.

```
array =
 [{'people'   =>'http://www.thing.com/this-post'},
  {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/that-post'},
  {'people'   =>'http://www.thing.com/nice-post'},
  {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/other-post'},
  {'people'   =>'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'},
  {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
  {'people'   =>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
  {'crayons'  =>'http://www.thing.com/the-blah'},
  {'chairs'   =>'http://www.thing.com/the-page',
    'crayons' =>'http://www.thing.com/blah'},
  {'balloons' =>'http://www.thing.com/the-page'}
 ]
```

We now merge the information from `array` into `hash`, and at the same time change the structure of `hash` to something more suitable:

```
result = merge_em(hash, array)
  #=> {"people"  =>{:qty=>"50",
  #                 :http=>["http://www.thing.com/this-post",
  #                         "http://www.thing.com/nice-post",
  #                         "http://www.thing.com/thingy-post",
  #                         "http://www.thing.com/the-post"]},
  #    "chairs"   =>{:qty=>"23",
  #                  :http=>["http://www.thing.com/the-page"]},
  #    "footballs"=>{:qty=>"5",
  #                  :http=>["http://www.thing.com/that-post",
  #                          "http://www.thing.com/other-post",
  #                          "http://www.thing.com/the-post"]},
  #    "crayons"  =>{:qty=>"1",
  #                  :http=>["http://www.thing.com/the-blah",
  #                          "http://www.thing.com/blah"]},
  #    "cat_lives"=>{:qty=>"9",
  #                  :http=>[]}}
```

I've assumed you want to look up the content of `result` with `hash`'s keys. It is therefore convenient to make the values associated with those keys hashes themselves, with keys `:qty` and `http`.  The former is for the values in `hash` (the naming may be wrong); the latter is an array containing the strings drawn from `array`.

This way, if we want the value for the key `"crayons"`, we could write:

```
result["crayons"]
#=> {:qty=>"1",
#    :http=>["http://www.thing.com/the-blah", "http://www.thing.com/blah"]}
```

or

```
irb(main):133:0> result["crayons"][:qty]
  #=> "1"
irb(main):134:0> result["crayons"][:http]
  #=> ["http://www.thing.com/the-blah", "http://www.thing.com/blah"]
```

**Explanation**

Let's go through this line-by-line.  First, we need to reference `hash.keys` more than once, so let's make it a variable:

```
hash_keys = hash.keys
  #=> ["people", "chairs", "footballs", "crayons", "cat_lives"]
```

We may as well convert this hash to the output format now.  We could do it during the merge operation below, but I think is clearer to do it as a separate step:

```
new_hash = hash_keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h|
  h[k] = { qty: hash[k], http: [] } }
  #=> {"people"   =>{:qty=>"50", :http=>[]},
  #    "chairs"   =>{:qty=>"23", :http=>[]},
  #    "footballs"=>{:qty=>"5",  :http=>[]},
  #    "crayons"  =>{:qty=>"1",  :http=>[]},
  #    "cat_lives"=>{:qty=>"9",  :http=>[]}}
```

Now we merge each (hash) element of `array` into `new_hash`:

```
array.each do |h|
  h.keys.each do |k|
    (new_hash.update({k=>h[k]}) { |k,g,http|
      { qty: g[:qty], http: (g[:http] << http) } }) if hash_keys.include?(k)
  end
end
```

The first hash `h` from `array` that is passed into the block by `each` is:

```
{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/this-post'}
```

which is assigned to the block variable `h`.  We next construct an array of `h`'s keys:

```
h.keys #=> ["people"]
```

The first of these keys, `"people"` (pretend there were more, as there would be in the penultimate element of `array`) is passed by its `each` into the inner block, whose block variable, `k`, is assigned the value `"people"`.  We then use [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) to merge the hash:

```
{k=>h[k]} #=> {"people"=>'http://www.thing.com/this-post'}
```

into `new_hash`, but only because:

```
hash_keys.include?(k)
  #=> ["people", "chairs", "footballs", "crayons", "cat_lives"].include?("people")
  #=> true
```

evaluates to `true`.  Note that this will evaluate to `false` for the key `"balloons"`, so the hash in `array` with that key will not be merged.  `update`'s block:

```
{ |k,g,http| { qty: g[:qty], http: (g[:http] << http) } }
```

is crucial.  This is `update`'s way of determining the value of a key that is in both `new_hash` and in the hash being merged, `{k=>h[k]}`.  The three block variables are assigned the following values by `update`:

```
k   : the key ("people")
g   : the current value of `new_hash[k]`
      #=> `new_hash["people"] => {:qty=>"50", :http=>[]}`
http: the value of the key/value being merged  
      #=> 'http://www.thing.com/this-post'
```

We want the merged hash value for key `"people"` to be:

```
{ qty: g[:qty], http: (g[:http] << http) }
#=> { qty: 50, http: ([] << 'http://www.thing.com/this-post') }
#=> { qty: 50, http: ['http://www.thing.com/this-post'] }
```

so now:

```
new_hash
      #=> {"people"   =>{:qty=>"50", :http=>['http://www.thing.com/this-post']},
      #    "chairs"   =>{:qty=>"23", :http=>[]},
      #    "footballs"=>{:qty=>"5",  :http=>[]},
      #    "crayons"  =>{:qty=>"1",  :http=>[]},
      #    "cat_lives"=>{:qty=>"9",  :http=>[]}}
```

We do the same for each of the other elements of `array`.

Lastly, we need to return the merged `new_hash`, so we make last line of the method:

```
new_hash
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a mix of hashes, arrays, and something in the middle. I'm going to *assume* the following inputs:

```
categories = {'people'=>'50',
'chairs'=>'23',
'footballs'=>'5',
'crayons'=>'1'}
```

and:

```
posts = [['people', 'http://www.thing.com/this-post'],
['footballs','http://www.thing.com/that-post'],
['people','http://www.thing.com/nice-post'],
['footballs','http://www.thing.com/other-post'],
['people','http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'],
['footballs','http://www.thing.com/the-post'],
['people','http://www.thing.com/the-post'],
['crayons','http://www.thing.com/the-blah'],
['chairs','http://www.thing.com/the-page']]
```

and the following output:

```
[['people', '50', ['http://www.thing.com/this-post', 'http://www.thing.com/nice-post', 'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post']],
[['footballs', '5', ['http://www.thing.com/the-post', 'http://www.thing.com/the-post']],
['crayons', '1', ['http://www.thing.com/the-blah']],
['chairs', '23' => {'chairs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-page']]]
```

In which case what you would need is:

```
categories.map do |name, count| 
  [name, count, posts.select do |category, _| 
     category == name 
   end.map { |_, post| post }] 
end
```

---

You need to understand the different syntax for Array and Hash in Ruby:

Hash:

```
{ 'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2' }
```

Array:

```
[ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4' ]
```

A Hash in ruby (like in every other language) can't have more than once instance of any single key, meaning that a Hash `{'key1' => 1, 'key1' => 2}` is invalid and will result in an unexpected value (duplicate keys are overridden - you'll have `{'key1' => 2 }`).

Comment: Thanks - coming from PHP  I need to get my head around the much more common usage of hashes in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

```
cat = [{'people'=>'50'},
       {'chairs'=>'23'},
       {'footballs'=>'5'},
       {'crayons'=>'1'}]
pages = [{'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/this-post'},
         {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/that-post'},
         {'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/nice-post'},
         {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/other-post'},
         {'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/thingy-post'},
         {'footballs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
         {'people'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-post'},
         {'crayons'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-blah'},
         {'chairs'=>'http://www.thing.com/the-page'}]

cat.map do |c|
  c.merge(Hash['pages',pages.collect{|h| h[c.keys.pop]}.compact])
end
#=> [{"people"=>"50", "pages"=>["http://www.thing.com/this-post", "http://www.thing.com/nice-post", "http://www.thing.com/thingy-post", "http://www.thing.com/the-post"]},
     {"chairs"=>"23", "pages"=>["http://www.thing.com/the-page"]}, 
     {"footballs"=>"5", "pages"=>["http://www.thing.com/that-post", "http://www.thing.com/other-post", "http://www.thing.com/the-post"]}, 
     {"crayons"=>"1", "pages"=>["http://www.thing.com/the-blah"]}]
```

Which is closer to your request but far less usable than some of the other posts.